# Story board version control conflicts

Tags: ios, objective-c, svn, storyboard, xib

I need clarification in story board version control conflicts, This is the scenario

1. In story board there are two view controllers, user1 edits VC1 and commit it to SVN user2
   edits the VC2 and update the local working copy. even user2 hasn't touch VC1
   Will it get conflict? because if I use xib instead of story board, VC1.xib and VC2.xib are different files It doesn't conflicts.

Comment: Even user1 never changed anything and just click the storyboard, it affects.... That's why I prefer to create separate storyboards for each developer.

Comment: So If I create a separate story board means how can i get other developer's story board?

Answer (score 0):

Simply opening the storyboard will make changes to it even if there are no actual changes. There are many way of solving your issue but I simply stash local storyboard changes before pushing unless I made an actual change to the storyboard.